# Different validation message and validation summary message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to show user different validation messages. One is at validation message list, and the other is near my edit box. Let's see by code:
My Model:

```
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be more than {1} characters.")]
string Name { get; set; }
```

In View:

```
@* in form *@

@*
My long message is here:
"Name cannot be more than 10 characters."
*@
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

@*
And my short validation message is here:
"*"
*@
@Html.TextBoxFor( m=> m.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
@*
But this validation message must be "*" instead of "Name cannot be more than 10 characters."
*@
```

Also I used `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "ShortMessage")`, But didn't worked. It shows "ShortMessage" as soon as page is loaded. Not after the validation failure.

How to acheve this? I'm using MVC4.
Any helps would be  appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "*")
```

This worked after including "Site.css" css file at heading section. You must insure "site.css" style classes before using validation.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
```

Use

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*")
```

This allows you to specify a message directly in the view, in this case an asterisk.

Comment: This is not the answer I want. I'd like to show asterisk after invalid entry.

Comment: In what way does this not accomplish that?

Comment: This writes asterisk after page is loaded. Not after invalid  entry. Writes asterisk directly to the page. But it must be hidden initially.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why site.css is required is because the validation summary and the validation messages are hidden/unhidden with CSS.
Open up site.css and you will see the following:

```
/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
color: #e80c4d;
font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
color: #e80c4d;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
display: none;
}
```

If you are not using site.css (as in the case I am having, inheriting a project) you will need to bring across these styles.

If it is still failing, check your ModelState in the back-end. If the IsValid property reads false, you will see the messages.